# how to terminate the execution of a loop when a key is press?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have scenario where I am displaying the content of a collection one by one until a key is press.  The problem is I cannot get the right code to determine when a key is being press.  I am designing in Visual Studio Lightswitch using VB.net language. The link below show the output of my program.  [Sample output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FOpN.png). The display keeps on looping until a user presses a key. also below is the sample code I am using.

```
    Private Sub Compliances_Activated()
        ' Write your code here.
       Do until "***the problem is here, I suppose to handle keyevents here but with no luck."***
            For Each I In Me.PendingCompliance
                If I.Incharge = "S1" Then
                    Me.Partic = I.Particulars
                    Me.ActionToUndertake = I.ActionToUndertake
                    Me.StatusOfCompliance = I.StatusOfCompliance
                    Dim controlcurr1 = Me.FindControl("Partic1")
                    AddHandler controlcurr1.ControlAvailable, _
                        Sub(sender As Object, e As ControlAvailableEventArgs)
                            Dim textbox = CType(e.Control, System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock)
                            textbox.Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(200, 0, 126, 230))
                            textbox.Height = (400.0)
                            textbox.FontSize = Convert.ToDouble(72.0)
                            textbox.FontFamily = New FontFamily("arial")
                            textbox.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.None

                        End Sub

                    Dim newsText1 = Me.FindControl("Partic1")
                    AddHandler newsText1.ControlAvailable, Sub(sender, e)

                                                               'Get the istance
                                                               Dim block = CType(e.Control, TextBlock)

                                                               'Set a different color, if you like
                                                               block.Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)

                                                               'Create an animation
                                                               Dim sb As New Storyboard
                                                               Dim colorAnim As New ColorAnimation
                                                               colorAnim.AutoReverse = True
                                                               colorAnim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
                                                               colorAnim.From = Colors.Blue
                                                               colorAnim.To = Colors.White
                                                               colorAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8)

                                                               'Apply the animation
                                                               Storyboard.SetTarget(colorAnim, block.Foreground)
                                                               Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnim, New PropertyPath("Color"))
                                                               sb.Children.Add(colorAnim)
                                                               sb.Begin()

                                                           End Sub
```

End If
                         Next
please help

Answer (score 0):

What is the  that you are using?

Probably it will be something like this

```
String answer;
If(answer!=" ")

break;
```

Comment: I am using VB.net in visual studio lightswitch.  There is a forum for VSLS but seems already inactive that's why I come here to seek for help.